# Using StringWithFormat generates different results using float and long

Tags: objective-c, ios7, stringwithformat

I created a class that holds 4 variables and 4 strings which are the same 4 vars but as strings,

in the h file I declared:

```
@property (assign) float num1;
@property (assign) float num2;
@property (assign) float num3;
@property (assign) long num4;

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *num1String;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *num2String;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *num3String;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSString *num4String;
```

in the init method, I passed a dictionary which I used to create the variables like this:

```
    num1 = [[dict objectForKey:@"num1"] floatValue];
    num2 = [[dict objectForKey:@"num2"] floatValue];
    num3 = [[dict objectForKey:@"num3"] floatValue];
    num4 = [[dict objectForKey:@"num4"] longValue];

    num1String = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", num1];
    num2String = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", num2];
    num3String = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.2f", num3];
    num4String = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",num4];
```

its get wired when I placed a break point after those line and checked the string types and the first 3 are NSString and num4String is NSMutableString !

---

my problem actually when I try to pass this string to another variable

```
    NSString *copyOfNum4String = model.num4String;
```

and instead of a string I get

```
Printing description of copyOfNum4String:
(NSString *) copyOfNum4String = 0x0000600001cb0740
```

which is crashing the app because the next thing I try to do is to get the last 4 characters.

can someone explain what is happening, and how to solve this ? (it has to be long because the number is 13 chars long )

---

EDIT: 
this is the dict print of the value :

```
[0] (null)  @"num1" : (long)2018420678770   
key NSTaggedPointerString * @"num1" 0xb79527f3826c0fa9
value   __NSCFNumber *  (long)2018420678770 0xa1c30c3a46fcec1d
```

Comment: Your code cannot compile. Properties in Objective-C are not instance variables, so you must use them this way: `self.num1 =` or `_num1 =`. Please, provide the `dictionary` as well - the way you initialize it is essential to understand the problem correctly.

Comment: thanks for you answer, the code compiles. maybe because its in the init method, I added dictinary value above

Comment: please provide the code that initializes the `dictionary`.

Comment: NSMutableDictionary *responseDictionary  = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.connectionData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil]; getting the dict from a response form a network call

Comment: Sorry, I cant compile the code. Maybe that's your problem - you're initializing a variable, but trying to get the property. Please, recheck it. Provide code with some context.

Comment: `assign`? MRC? Really?

Comment: @MaxPevsner if you synthesize the properties you dont need self or _ . I also added at the bottom of my question the print of the value that Im trying to get

Comment: @Cy-4AH what do you mean by that ? did I do something wrong ?

Comment: @alex that's why I'm asking for more context. Synthesizing properties is not a default for almost five years. You should have mention that or provide the full source code.

Comment: You need to start reading about memory management in iOS first.

Comment: @MaxPevsner sorry, Im kind of new to this, so it didn't come to mind

Comment: @Cy-4AH I do read but there is so much to learn that I cant know it all. what did I miss ?